# How to encrypt xml elements?

Tags: xml, serialization, encryption, xsd

I have auto generated a class (vb.net) from an xsd schema (with xsd.exe). I populate the objects properties with data and serialize the object to xml and store the xml in a string. In my xml I have to encrypt some of the elements. What is the best way to do this?

Can I encrypt my objects properties before I serialize the object to xml? In my documentation to the xsd schema it says that all the encrypted values (elements) has to be string, but when I auto generate the class from the xsd schem the Birth number is set to date and not string…? And birth number is part of the elements I have to encrypt.
I want to use PKI to encrypt the symmetric key I want to use to encrypt the xml elements.

Can somebody help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward solution might be to expose two versions of each property, encrypted and unencrypted, and mark all the unencrypted versions with [XmlIgnore].

If you're unable to edit the auto-generated classes, and you want those properties to be encrypted, then you could add un-encrypted wrapper properties in the partial class, e.g.

== in the auto-generated file:

```
class MyClass {
  String SensitiveProperty { get; set; }
}
```

== in the not-auto-generated partial file:

```
partial class MyClass {
  [XmlIgnore]
  String SensitivePropertyDecrypted {
    get {
      return CryptoHelper.Decrypt(SensitiveProperty);
    }
    set {
      SensitiveProperty = CryptoHelper.Encrypt(value);
    }
  }
}
```

... where "CryptoHelper" is a class you've written to support the encryption scheme you're hoping to achieve (i.e. using the symmetric key you've passed using PKI).

Comment: Thanks! But how can I use  XmlIgnore (I can’t do any changes directly in the auto generated class, because this class has to be updated regularly)? I have a class.partial.vb that extend the auto generated class, can I do some changes in this class?

Comment: I've updated my answer to take into account the auto-generated classes

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain a little bit more? Isn’t it the SensitivProperty that should be marked XmlIgnore? And this property is in the auto generated class… Do I have to make new properties in the partial file, both for the SensitiveProperty and the SensitivePropertyDecrypt, and mark the Sensitive property with XmlIgnore?
Then when I serialize my class object, only the properties in the partial file without the XmlIgnore will be serialized? What about the properties in the auto generated class?

Comment: All properties in the auto generated class will get serialized, and you can't mark them [XmlIgnore], as you don't want to be editing that file (in case you regenerate it). In the above example, SensitiveProperty will be encrypted, and your code will have to read/write through the "SensitivePropertyDecrypted" property. You want SensitiveProperty to be serialized (hence no [XmlIgnore]) and you don't want the decrypted version to be serialized (hence the [XmlIgnore])

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to do what you suggested!